# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'customersCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

The first time I used angular.js, using http request to dynamically render data, I encountered such a strange problem, there is no problem with the following code alone, but if you put it in the page I want to do , it will give an error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'customersCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

But I have defined customersCtrl,

```
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
```

This is my code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:17900/flower/flowers?flowerName")
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.names = result.data.body;
                });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You should define the controller before you include `ng-app` or `ng-cotroller`

Comment: can you add your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You must define the `<script>` tag outside of the `ng-app` element. Should you use inline `js`, the script tag must be defined before the `ng-app` element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.names = ["Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Aaryn", "Aayan", "Aazaan", "Abaan", "Abbas"]

    // $http.get("http://localhost:17900/flower/flowers?flowerName")
    //   .then(function (result) {
    //   $scope.names = result.data.body;
    // });
  });
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Note

I recommend you to use version `1.7.5`

Comment: @Xuan Did you run the code snippet? It works  as expected. Your problems lies some other place. The hardest part of the solving a problem is is to understand what the problem is. In this case it is as such since you have provided very little info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you include the angular controller in html tags before you define it, So angular compiler could not find the `customersCtrl` as function.
Edit Your code like this :

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$http' function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:17900/flower/flowers?flowerName")
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.names = result.data.body;
                });
        }]);
 </script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl"></div>
```

Comment: @Xuan But's it's work fine for me.Which version of angular you used?

Comment: I am using v1.3.2